# Codeigniter 4 redirecting POST request to "/" when call made from cURL

Tags: php, codeigniter, http, curl, post

I am writing an API and one of the methods is a POST that processes the data passed in the call and sets a response status. When I make a call to this method from a website form submission, it works fine, but when I make the same call from the command line via cURL, it redirects to "/". Do you know why that is?

cURL:

```
curl --location --request POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"name":"John Doe","email":"johndoe@example.com"}' \
-w "Status: %{http_code}" \
http://localhost:8080/api/test
```

Method:

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\CLIRequest;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest;

class Api extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        $postData = $this->request->getPost();

        if (!empty($postData)) {
            $name = $postData['name'];
            $email = $postData['email'];

            echo "Received data: Name = $name, Email = $email";

            $responseStatus = 'success'; // Example: 'success', 'error', etc.

            return $this->response->setJSON(['status' => $responseStatus]);
        } else {
            return $this->response->setJSON(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'No data received']);
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, I have this route set in Routes.php:

```
$routes->post('api/test', 'Api::test');
```

Comment: I'm don't know anything about CodeIgniter internals, but when you submit a form the Content-Type is not `application/json`, which is what you send using your curl command. Is there any chance the call to `getPost` on `$this->request` could create issues when the content-type is not what it expects ?

Comment: Even if I change the test function to just ```$this->response->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');echo json_encode($response);``` I still get the redirect issue, so I don't think it has anything to do with the contents of the function. It's either the cURL command (which I don't think is the issue), or some settings I have in Codeigniter. That is my guess

Comment: Issue of Authentication/session not initialized?

Comment: @b126 I don't think so, since the GET methods work fine. That would make sense though. Looking into it.

Comment: @EvanAppleby: how can it work with GET params (querystring) since you are using getPost(), you say it's working through a classic POST form a,d your route is only defined to deal with post?

Comment: @b126 I meant that there are other functions in that same controller (all GET) and all those work.

Comment: @EvanAppleby You can copy curl command from network tab in browser and see all the headers sent when you call the end point from browser to debug further on this. By removing one at a time you can see which header or param makes the different here.

Comment: @Nish found the answer! It was related to my CSRF protection. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue! It was the CSRF protection.  I just had to update it to exclude API calls:

```
public $globals = [
    'before' => [
        // 'honeypot',
        'csrf' => ['except' => ['api/*]],
        // 'invalidchars',
    ],
    'after' => [
        'toolbar',
        // 'honeypot',
        // 'secureheaders',
    ],
];
```